# PHP form is always in the submitted state

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a simple login form, but `echo $_POST['loginButton'];` always outputs LOG IN  without filling the form and clicking the submit button.
Why is the it outputting LOG IN. I want to check if the submit button is pressed and then I would like to get the values of username and password.All the code are in the same `register.php`. Here is the code:

```
    <?php
// if(isset($_POST['loginButton'])){
//     // Login button was pressed
//     echo 'Logged in';
// }
echo $_POST['loginButton'];
?>

<!--Login Form -->
<form action="register.php" id="loginForm" method="POST">
    <h2>Login to your acount</h2>
    <!-- Username -->
    <p>
        <label for="loginUsername">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="loginUsername" name="loginUsername" required >
    </p>
    <!-- Password -->
    <p>
        <label for="loginPassword">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="loginPassword" name="loginPassword" required >
    </p>
    <!-- Submit -->
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="LOG IN" name="loginButton">
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Always? Like when you press "refresh" after clicking the button, or after you open new tab and then visit your page?

Comment: Yes, the output is always LOG IN after refreshing the page.

Comment: In that case, your browser should have shown you a warning that you are about to send form data _again_, no …?

Comment: NO the browser does not show any warning, Note: All the code are in the same register.php file

Comment: And thats the whole file? Also, open your register.php in new tab.

Comment: yes, it no longer shows submitted

Comment: Why does that work in new tab but not when refreshing

Comment: Sure, because you were still sending the the form with refresh (it could take like 30 seconds of google, but why dont ask question on SO, right?)

Comment: Why localhost operates like that? In javascript, it works fine when reloading the page.

Comment: You were refreshing the POST action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this after `if(isset($_POST['loginButton'])`

```
  && !empty($_POST["loginButton"])){

         echo 'Logged in'. "\r\n" ;
         echo $_POST['loginUsername'] ."\r\n";
         echo $_POST['loginPassword'];
     }else{  
        echo "Not logged in";
```

You did have else statement if the user is not logged in.